# How can i access Javascript objects from python side on jupyter-notebook cells?

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, svg.js

I mean i use SVGjs with %%javascript magic cells and for example create a  rectangle and then i want to access  and change  this rectangle using python code.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you want to invoke the change on the server you could use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/WebSockets) to transmit the data. I'm not familiar with python but I'm pretty sure there's a library for websockets

Comment: @schroffl thanks for answering. But thats not exactly what i want. Jupyter - notebook has already  websockets. However its so low level. I just want render  a animation with python  using js objects. (By the way python has lots of websockets such as pywebsocket and ws4py )